# ReactJs - redirect url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to reactjs - and if I hit an error page on a subpage - because the url is wrong - I am looking to find a way to redirect the page to another.

So de/dienstleistungen/isdfisf -- spelt wrong
redirect to de/dienstleistungen

I've tried to write a function to handle this but no luck

```
  if (!lang.serviceIntro[0][service]) {
    console.log('undefined', this)
    this.context.router.push('/de/dienstleistungen')
  }
```

Failed context type: Invalid context `router` of type `object` supplied to `PlainHeader`, expected `function`.

Answer (score 0):

are you using react-router? and if used which version are you on it? 
Check out https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history which is currently on v4. This is my code

```
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        let token = ... // achieve token
        if (!token) {
            this.props.history.push('/login');
        }
    }

    render() {
        ....
    }
}
```

my code in main page checking if not authenticated will redirect to login page programmatically. Props *this.props.history* will be passed by react router through .
Check the docs above for more information. Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you should declare `contextTypes.router` as an object, router was a function in older versions

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```